# Data not visible

Tags: android, kotlin

1. My Variable Class

```kotlin
data class QnaVariable( val questionOne: String, val answerOne : String,  val questionTwo: String, val answerTwo : String)
```

2. My ViewModel Class

```kotlin
    val item = QnaVariable("I am unable to login my account",
        "You can reset password using the Reset Password in My account Page. If you are still unable to access your account, then please call our customer care.",
        "Still need help?",
        "Have a queries? please get in touch and we will be happy to help you")

}
```

1. My Fragment Class

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = FragmentQuestionAnswerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

        val model = viewModel.item

        //binding.questionHeading1.text = model.toString()
        binding.questionHeading1.text = QNAdapter(myList).toString()

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return FragmentQuestionAnswerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false).apply { 
    binding = this
    //TODO: write code to update your ui
}.root
```

Modify binding part like this.

Comment: @Dev happy hacking :)

Comment: Hey will you solve one more doubt?

Comment: Please post a new question. And, if my answer is correct, please click the Accept button on the left side of the post.

Comment: Ok ill post it today so do have a look on it